# SwiftUI: How to create single line label that shrinks when vertically compressed?

Tags: ios, swiftui

How can I create a single-line label that shrinks font size when compressed vertically?

The natural choice of combining `minimumScaleFactor` with `lineLimit` is producing unexpected results.

See this example. Without any line limit, the label compresses vertically and adjusts font size correctly. Adding `.lineLimit(1)` prevents the top label from reducing font size.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let text:String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.center, spacing:0 ) {
            Text(self.text)
                .font(Font.system(size: 60.0))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.15)
                .background(Color.blue)
            
            Rectangle()
                .strokeBorder()
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height:60.0)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack(spacing:20) {
            ContentView(text:"A quick brown fox")
                .lineLimit(1)
            Text("Line limit 1")

            ContentView(text:"150")
                .lineLimit(1)
            Text("Line limit 1")

            ContentView(text:"A quick brown fox")
            Text("No line limit")

            ContentView(text:"150")
            Text("No line limit")
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the best workaround I could come up with that doesn't assume a string length.

Use GeometryReader to explicitly scale the font size of the label depending on a known height of its container. `minimumScaleFactor` continues to take care of scaling the Text horizontally. A bit ugly since you have to know the height of the label for a default font size. In my app this is a sufficient workaround.

Please reply if you have a better answer!

```
GeometryReader {reader in
    Text(self.text)
        .font(Font.system(size: 60.0 * reader.size.height / 80))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.15)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .background(Color.blue)
}
```

Full Interactive example:

https://gist.github.com/mikebernardo/011d9f6839baac40b359e0ad18b4b0d4

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

`.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. Prevents font scaling.